# Asterisk call file

Tags: asterisk

Good day. The call file details are

```
Channel: SIP/voipswitch/971556710034
MaxRetries: 6
RetryTime: 20
WaitTime: 30
Context: default
Extension: 971556710034
Priority: 1
```

with this setting I can connect call on my phone. Once call get received asterisk delete this file and stop calling. But I want to call on my phone after every 30 min and will receive every time.

Can some one please help to do this.

Comment: Create this file somewhere and copy it to `asterisk/outgoing` directory using crontab every 30 min.

Comment: Thanks for good idea. I am new in linux. can you pls write a crontab for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in **`/etc/crontab`**

```
*/30 * * * * asterisk cp /path/to/call/file /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing
```

This will copy call file to asterisk outgoing directory every 30 min.

Don't forget to restart crontab service.

```
service crontab restart
```

Comment: Note, you also need check that currently in outgoing folder not too many files. Asterisk can crash if too many files.